# Securing access to a website on IIS

Tags: security, iis-7, iis-7.5

I've got a website running on IIS7.5. I want to ask for credentials (fixed user/password) on access to the website. I don't need to do anything with those credentials - just to make sure the user knows them.

I'd like to make it transparent to the website (it shouldn't "concern" the website).

Is there some elegant way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way is to create some local user accounts on your server and then enable Windows Authentication on your site in IIS. When users visit the site they will be asked for credentials, which will be validated against the Windows user database.

Comment: And I should let permissions on the website folder for that user, right?

Comment: @roman, sorry I should have mentioned that. Yes you will need to give permission to those users to be able access the website folder.